# How do I select an anchor containing a specific word with jquery / css

Tags: jquery, css

I have tried

```
$('a[title="*"]').find('contains("PDF")').css({'background':'red'});
```

Which I know isn't what I want as its clearly broken.

Sorry to clarify the Im looking for a word occuring in the title

Comment: What is the `<a>` tag you are looking for?

Comment: It has classes rounded and shadow but thats not enough

Comment: I meant what does the HTML look like?

Comment: What is the meaning of **contains(PDF)**? If you want to select links with a **title** tag and containing the word **PDF**, you should try `$("a[title]:contains('PDF')")`. **find()** expects a selector expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sFkPN/1/)**

```
$('a[title*="PDF"]').css({'background':'red'});
```

**For searching with ignore case**

```
$('a[title*="pdf"]').filter(function(){
    if(this.title.toLowerCase().indexOf("pdf") != -1)
         return $(this);
}).css({'background':'red'});
```

Comment: Or if he wanted an exact match, `'a[title=PDF]'`

Comment: Many thanks it was *= I was looking for, will accept in a while

Comment: Updated my answer with ignore case too @Kevin B

Comment: The ignore case version doesn't work.  It should be: `$('a[title]').filter(function(){`.  Also `.filter` needs you to return true or false, not the element (or jQuery object).  Just do `return this.title.toLowerCase().indexOf("pdf") !== -1;`.  http://jsfiddle.net/sFkPN/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[title*="PDF"]').css({'background':'red'});
```

Comment: This will match any a tag where the title attrivute contains PDF.

Answer (score -1):

If its a specific title, it is simply:

```
$("a[title*='specificTitle']");
```

Comment: `*=` means "contains".  For a "specific" title, you'd want just `=`.

Comment: Specific and exact are two different meanings. specifically searching for apple, both applesauce and snapple are a match. Considering he wants a 'contains' its appropriate to use *=